# QGIS Export file Automatic Geometry Type issue

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

It appears that the new version of QGIS has an issue whereby if you save a new file (using 'Export > Save Features as) and then select 'Automatic' for the geometry type, it does not migrate the geometry type correctly.
For instance, I am saving a Mapinfo TAB file of geometry type Polygon (multipart). I perform the above export to a new file of same type and select the automatic geometry type.
The new file that is created SAYS 'Polygon (Multipart)' - however, attempting to save any records into this file throws an error message
"Geometry type is invalid for this format"

The work around is when exporting the file, to select the actual geometry type in the drop down on the export menu. Again, the output file is exactly the same and geometry format says Polygon Multi-part, but this time, saving records works.

**Does anyone else experience this with file formats other than Mapinfo?**

QGIS v3.16